# Why Microsoft has put 2 different options for creating Unique Indexes on a table in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, indexing, unique

Why Microsoft has put 2 different options for creating Unique Indexes on a table in SQL Server 2008?

Manage Indexes/Keys :

1 ) type = Unique Key   ==> IsUnique = Yes  (IsUnique is disabled)
2 ) type = Index   ==> IsUnique = Yes

Thank you

Comment: or you forgot the smiley or you should lay of the coffee.

Answer (score 5):

They map to two different `SQL` commands:

```
ALTER TABLE … ADD CONSTRAINT … UNIQUE
```

and

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX … ON …
```

`CONSTRAINT UNIQUE` is a logical concept, while `UNIQUE INDEX` is its physical implementation.

In `SQL Server`, `CONSTRAINT UNIQUE` is always backed up by a unique index which is implicitly created with the same name as the constraint, so these commands are effectively the same.

The only difference from user's point of view is that the constraint can be implicitly named, but you should always provide an explicit name for an index.

Comment: Okay, I'll bite... Is there a difference in the physical implementation? AFAIK, adding a unique constraint or a unique index both achieve the same thing... or don't they?

Comment: @Lieven: as for now, there is no difference, but in future releases there can be. `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` is a logical concept (make sure that the column's value is unique), `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX` is a physical concept (create a `B-Tree` that does not allow duplicates). If some wise guy will invent a more efficient way to ensure uniqueness, `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` can use this efficient way, while `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX` cannot.

Answer (score 0):

This is what Google finds (for SQL Server 2000 though):

> The short answer is that a unique
>   index is just an index, whereas a
>   unique constraint is a unique index
>   that's listed as a constraint object
>   in the database. In the sysobjects
>   table, the unique constraint will have
>   an xtype value of "UQ." But does a
>   unique constraint have any additional
>   behavior that a unique index doesn't
>   have—or vice versa? The answer to that
>   question, it turns out, takes a big of
>   digging.
>
> ...

Source: [Unique Constraints and Unique Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224827%28SQL.80%29.aspx)